# Finding stop_codon

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, bioinformatics

I am trying to find the start and stop codons in my cds. I have used regular expressions but when I run this python script I get an empty list for the stop codons. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
std_code = {"TTT":"F|Phe","TTC":"F|Phe","TTA":"L|Leu","TTG":"L|Leu","TCT":"S|Ser","TCC":"S|Ser",
            "TCA":"S|Ser","TCG":"S|Ser", "TAT":"Y|Tyr","TAC":"Y|Tyr","TAA":"*|Stp","TAG":"*|Stp",
            "TGT":"C|Cys","TGC":"C|Cys","TGA":"*|Stp","TGG":"W|Trp", "CTT":"L|Leu","CTC":"L|Leu",     
            "CTA":"L|Leu","CTG":"L|Leu","CCT":"P|Pro","CCC":"P|Pro","CCA":"P|Pro","CCG":"P|Pro",
            "CAT":"H|His","CAC":"H|His","CAA":"Q|Gln","CAG":"Q|Gln","CGT":"R|Arg","CGC":"R|Arg",
            "CGA":"R|Arg","CGG":"R|Arg", "ATT":"I|Ile","ATC":"I|Ile","ATA":"I|Ile","ATG":"M|Met",
            "ACT":"T|Thr","ACC":"T|Thr","ACA":"T|Thr","ACG":"T|Thr", "AAT":"N|Asn","AAC":"N|Asn",
            "AAA":"K|Lys","AAG":"K|Lys","AGT":"S|Ser","AGC":"S|Ser","AGA":"R|Arg","AGG":"R|Arg",
            "GTT":"V|Val","GTC":"V|Val","GTA":"V|Val","GTG":"V|Val","GCT":"A|Ala","GCC":"A|Ala",
            "GCA":"A|Ala","GCG":"A|Ala", "GAT":"D|Asp","GAC":"D|Asp","GAA":"E|Glu",
            "GAG":"E|Glu","GGT":"G|Gly","GGC":"G|Gly","GGA":"G|Gly","GGG":"G|Gly"}

cds = ("ATGCTAGCGGTAAATCGTGAATAGGCCTAA")
for i in range (0, len(cds),3):
    print cds[i:i+3]

def translate (cds, std_code):
    protein = ""
    for i in range (0,len(cds),3):
        codon = cds[i:i+3]
        protein = protein + std_code[codon]
    return protein
print translate(cds, std_code)
def codon_usage(cds):
    usage = {}
    for i in range(0,len(cds),3):
        codon = cds[i:i+3]
        if usage.has_key(codon):
            usage[codon] += 1
        else:
            usage[codon] = 1
    return usage
print codon_usage(cds)


import re
pat = '(ATG)+?(?:TAA|TGA|TAG)'
reg = re.compile(pat)
def stop_codons(cds, messages=None,s=0,reg=reg):
    stop_codons = []
    while True:
        ma = reg.search(cds[s:])
        if ma:
            if ma.group(1) == 'ATG':
                break
            else:
                stop_codons.append(ma.group.upper())
                s = s + ma.start() + 1
        else:
            break
    return stop_codons
print stop_codons(cds, messages=None, s=0,reg=reg)
```

Comment: you could also ask http://biostars.org

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using [Biopython](http://biopython.org)? It has all sorts of built-in tools for dealing with sequences, and can save you a lot of time if you're doing anything related to bioinformatics. In particular, the [`Seq`](http://biopython.org/wiki/Seq) object is just what you're looking for:

```
>>> from Bio.Seq import Seq
>>> from Bio.Alphabet import generic_dna
>>> my_dna = Seq("AGTACACTGGT", generic_dna)
>>> my_dna
Seq('AGTACACTGGT', DNAAlphabet())
>>> my_dna.find("ACT")
5
```

I highly recommend reading the [tutorial](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc16) and the [API documentation](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Seq-module.html) to find info on things like alphabets, codon tables (`Bio.Data.CodonTable`), etc.

Answer (score 2):

I see a couple of problems with your `stop_codons` function.  First, your regex:

```
(ATG)+?(?:TAA|TGA|TAG)
```

As it is written, this is searching for repetitions of your start codon, followed by a stop codon.  Were your regex as it is written were to match, it would just return the start codons and nothing else.  If you want to find the first stop codon after a start codon, you can try:

```
(?<=ATG)(?:[ACGT]{3})*(TAA|TGA|TAG)
```

Second, it appears that if your regex matches the start codon, it will break the loops and return your list of `stop_codons`, which assuming every sequence you pass into this function includes a start codon before a stop, would always result in an empty list being returned.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll also second MattDMo, you should look into BioPython if you are unfamiliar with it.